# Добавление элементов в TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms

После добавления в MainTreeView(создавал через toolbox) элементов они не отображаются на экране, хотя в отладчике видно что они добавились. В чем может быть проблема?

```
TreeView treeView2 = new TreeView();
treeView2.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("123"));
treeView2.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("456"));

TreeNode[] nodes= new TreeNode[2];
treeView2.Nodes.CopyTo(nodes, 0);

MainTreeView.Nodes.AddRange(nodes);
```

Суть в том, что мне нужно ветки одного дерева копировать в другое дерево.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя использовать один и тотже Node в разных TreeView. В вашем случае `CopyTo` не работает так как вам хотелсь бы. Он не выполняет так называемое "глубокое копирование".
Если мы заглянем в исходники, то `CopyTo` всего лишь вызывает метод `Array.Copy();` который не делает глубокого копирования.

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TreeNodeCollection.cs,4fa2f1e81962f906,references

Вместо него нужно использовать `Clone()`

```
    TreeView treeView2 = new TreeView();
    treeView2.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("123"));
    treeView2.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("456"));

    MainTreeView.BeginUpdate();
    foreach (var node in treeView2.Nodes)
        MainTreeView.Nodes.Add((TreeNode)node.Clone());
    MainTreeView.EndUpdate();
```

`Clone()` осуществляет глубокое копирование массива, а `CopyTo()` – поверхностное. Поверхностное копирование массива копирует только сами элементы объекта класса TreeNodeCollection, независимо от того являются они ссылочными или значимыми типами.
Копирования объектов, на которые ссылаются ссылочные типы не происходит. Ссылки в новом объекте класса TreeNodeCollection указывают на те же объекты, что и ссылки в оригинальном TreeNodeCollection. Глубокое копирование копирует как элементы класса TreeNodeCollection, так и объекты, на которые они явно или неявно ссылаются.

Comment: Попробовал. Ничего не происходит.

Comment: @Lightness, а если не копировать туда элементы, а вставить новые как в первый, работает?

Comment: работает если сделать вот так             MainTreeView.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("123"));     Но мне не нужно создавать новую ветку, мне нужно взять из другого дерева уже готовую ветку с многими данными, и вставить их в главное дерево.

Comment: @Lightness, поправил

Comment: Спасибо, работает! Но в чем же была проблема?

Comment: @Lightness,  возможно в том что CopyTo работает не так как ожидалось, тоесть не клонирует массив, а созадет на него новые указатели, сейчас проверю. Нельзя использовать один и тотже Node в разных TreeView

Comment: да, нельзя. см. мой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Если надо переместить (т.е. move, а не copy), то TreeNode надо удалить из TreeView, в котором он находится, и только после этого добавить в другой TreeView.
А если требуется копировать TreeNode, то надо создать его клон, который добавляется в другой TreeView.

Comment: но ведь CopyTo в исходном коде автора, разве не делает копии? Почему Clone работает а CopyTo нет?

Comment: точно сейчас не скажу, но если интересно, то вы можете посмотреть на реализацию TreeNodeCollection -- [тут](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TreeNodeCollection.cs,27)